# Mocking an outgoing request inside an async redux action in a node app doesn't work

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, redux

I just started building a small app using node and redux by adding on to [react-redux-starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit).
I am now trying to test an async action which performs an API call, while adhering closely to the [redux example](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html).
I am using the package [isomorphic-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch) to perform the request and [fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock) to mock it, but when I run my tests, it performs a real request to my API.
I already noticed that fetch-mock works as expected when I perform the API call right in my it-block, but actually I want to test an *imported function* that performs the API call.
What do I need to do to get it to work also for an imported function?

*This is what my action looks like:*

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill()

const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch')

export const authenticateUserCredentials = ({email, password}) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return fetch('http://localhost:3005/v1/sign_in', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password
      })
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log('json', json)
      })
      .catch((reason) => {
        console.log('CATCHED ERROR:', reason.name, reason.message)
      })
  }
}

export const actions = {
  authenticateUserCredentials
}
```

*And in my spec file:*

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { actions } from 'redux/modules/session'
const fetchMock = require('fetch-mock')

const middlewares = [ thunk ]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)

describe('(Async Action Creator) Authenticate user credentials', function () {
  const EMAIL = 'a@b.de'
  const TOKEN = '893irnjkklfnt'
  const PASSWORD = 'foobar'

  beforeEach(function () {
    fetchMock.mock(
      'http://localhost:3005/v1/sign_in',
      'POST', {
        status: 200,
        body: '{"email":"' + EMAIL + '","token":"' + TOKEN + '"}'
      }
    )
  })

  afterEach(function () {
    fetchMock.restore()
  })

  it('creates SIGN_IN when credentials are valid', (done) => {
    const initialState = {}

    const expectedActions = [
      { type: AUTHENTICATING, payload: undefined },
      { type: SIGN_IN, payload: {email: EMAIL, token: TOKEN} }
    ]
    const store = mockStore(initialState, expectedActions, () => {
      return done()
    })
    store.dispatch(
      actions.authenticateUserCredentials({
        email: EMAIL,
        password: PASSWORD
      })
    )
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this package solves the problem: https://github.com/spaceviewinc/fetch-mock-forwarder.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to not assign `isomorphic-fetch` to a constant as it will already assign itself as a global variable. `fetch-mock` is designed to work with `fetch` as a global as that's what the standard says `fetch` should be. It is possible to get it to work with `fetch` assigned to some other variable, but it means jumping through unnecessary hoops.